# Converting Date Difference to Integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains two date columns and I want to derive a column containing the difference between the two dates:

```
cm['Duration'] = cm['EndDate'] - cm['StartDate']
```

This newly created column is actually of type datetime.timedelta whereas I just want it to be an integer. Tried the following:

```
cm['Duration'] = (cm['EndDate'] - cm['StartDate']).days
```

but get the following error which makes sense:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'
```

Any thoughts on how to get this issue resolved would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: use `cm['Duration'] = (cm['EndDate'] - cm['StartDate']).dt.days`, unfortunately dupe, so no answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cm['Duration'] = (cm['EndDate'] - cm['StartDate']).apply(lambda s: s.days)
```